# Prove that if $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers and $n|m$, then $n \leq m$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, proof-verification

$n|m$ means $n$ divides $m$, i.e. $m = kn$ for some integer $k$. I was told to use the fact that $1$ is the smallest positive integer to prove this.

Using $m = kn$ and the fact that I am dealing with natural numbers, plugging in the smallest possible value for $k$ gets me $m = n$. As $k$ increases, the value of $n$ decreases while the value of $m$ increases. So $n$ must be either equal to $m$ or less than $m$, thus $n \leq m$.

I'm not sure if this is a valid proof, though.

Comment: it is a matter of definitions : what is the definition of $n |m$, of $n \le m$, what do you already know on multiplications, divisions, etc. and what proof system (what logic theory) are you using : the Peano axioms, the ZF(C), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can prove by contraposition.  $n>m \Longrightarrow 0<\frac mn<1$ (so $\frac mn \notin \mathbb{N})$ $\Longrightarrow n \nmid m$.

Answer (score 4):

Since $m,n\in\mathbb N$, $m\ge1$ and $n\ge1$. Thus, $k\ge0$. If $k=0$, then $m=0$. Thus, $k\ge1$.
$$k\ge1$$
As $n\gt0$,
$$nk\ge n$$
$$m=nk\ge n\Rightarrow m\ge n$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use that the product of positve integers is a positive integer: If $m=kn$ then either $k=1$ (and so $m=n\ge n$) or $k>1$ and so $k=l+1$ for some natural number $l$. In that case $m=kn=n+ln>n$.